# A two-level symbolic link chasing function in Tcl

Tags: tcl, environment-modules

The upshot of what I'm trying to do is write a *Tcl* function that is equivalent to the following shell:

```
get_real_home () {
    dirname $(ls -l $(ls -l $(which "$1") | awk '{print $NF}') | awk '{print $NF'})
}
```

In short, this gives me the name of the directory that contains the actual binary that runs when I give it the name of a program managed by the [Debian alternatives system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) by following a symlink, usually in `/usr/bin`, to another symlink in `/etc/alternatives/`, which points at the executable (or whatever) of the alternative currently in use. For example:

```
$ get_real_home java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin
```

The reason that I want to do this is that I am using [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/), whose “native language” is *Tcl*, to manage the environment settings (chiefly `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) for a number of compilers, interpreters, and libraries. This utility is pretty well a *de facto* standard on clusters.

For *Java* in particular (where there are many alternatives), it would be convenient to be able to set the environment (e.g. `JAVA_HOME`) to the right value for the current *Debian* alternative via an *Environment Modules* module that would “know” where the current *Debian* alternative points at. For that, the above symlink chaser is handy.

Of course, I *could* just stick what I already have (above) into a shell script and call that from *Tcl* in *Environment Modules*: a pragmatic if inelegant solution. I'd prefer the better “native” *Tcl* solution, but owing to my total ignorance of *Tcl*, I'm having difficulty doing it, despite it seeming like it should be trivial.

I'm sure this *is* trivial to someone who knows *Tcl*, but that isn't me :(

Comment: Take a look at the Tcl ``file`` commands, especially `file link`. (see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/file.htm )

Comment: Thanks. I had found this information. Putting it all together is the hard part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file normalize` command makes this virtually effortless.

```
set javaBinDir [file dirname [file normalize {*}[auto_execok java]]]
```

(The `auto_execok` command is a Tcl library procedure that does Gipsy Magic to work out how to run the given program. For the `java` program, it's equivalent to `exec which`; for shell builtins, it's trickier. It returns a list, a singleton in this case. I'm expanding it *just in case* you've got a directory with a space in the name, or some non-balanced braces. Unlikely…)

---

If the target itself is a link, you need a little more work.

```
set java [file normalize [lindex [auto_execok java] 0]]
while {[file type $java] eq "link"} {
    # Ought to check for link loops...
    set java [file normalize [file join [file dirname $java] [file readlink $java]]]
}
puts "java really resolves to $java"
```

`file normalize` won't do this for you automatically, as you might be wanting to refer to the link itself and not the thing it refers to. Fortunately, `file join` does The Right Thing when presented with both relative and absolute components; this appears to work when I try it in a (simulated) example.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't actually work. I think it might be because `normalize` (seems to) canonicalize what you give it, so it will resolve symbolic links in directories, but doesn't resolve a symbolic link if you give it one. Your example above just gives me `/usr/bin/java`. I'll check out `auto_execok`, though. Thanks again.

Comment: @Emmet Ah! I misunderstood you. Try the edited answer…

Comment: Right. That's what I wanted and a good deal more compact than my own answer (below).

Answer (score 1):

So, I answer my own question a couple of hours later. It's verbose, but it works. Below gives me the answer I want when invoked as a command, although it won't be used like that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Equivalent to shell "which", returning the first occurence of its
# argument, cmd, on the PATH:
proc which {cmd} {
    foreach dir [split $::env(PATH) :] {
        set fqpn $dir/$cmd
        if { [file exists $fqpn] } {
            return $fqpn
        }
    }
}

# True if 'path' exists and is a symbolic link:
proc is_link {path} {
    return [file exists $path] && [string equal [file type $path] link]
}

# Chases a symbolic link until it resolves to a file that
# isn't a symlink:
proc chase {link} {
    set max_depth 10 ; # Sanity check
    set i 0
    while { [is_link $link] && $i < $max_depth } {
        set link [file link $link]
        incr i
    }
    if { $i >= $max_depth } {
        return -code error "maximum link depth ($max_depth) exceeded"
    }
    return $link
}

# Returns the "true home" of its argument, a command:
proc get_real_home {cmd} {
    set utgt [chase [which $cmd]]    ; # Ultimate target
    set home [file dirname $utgt]    ; # Directory containing target
    if { [string equal bin [file tail $home]] } {
        set home [file dirname $home]
    }
    return $home
}

# Not worried about command-line argument validation because
# none of the above will be used in a command context
set cmd  [lindex $argv 0]       ; # Command
set home [get_real_home $cmd]   ; # Ultimate home
puts "$cmd -> $home"
```

Comment: For someone with "total ignorance" of Tcl, that's pretty impressive.

Comment: I think that might be the nicest thing anyone has ever said to me :)